# CreateIconIndirect - interpretation of pixel data

Tags: winapi

I would like to create an icon manually with CreateIconIndirect as follows:

```cpp
HDC hDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC( nullptr );

BITMAPINFO bmiMask = {};
bmiMask.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof( bmiMask.bmiHeader );
bmiMask.bmiHeader.biWidth = 16;
bmiMask.bmiHeader.biHeight = -16; // starts with top row
bmiMask.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmiMask.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
BYTE *byMask = nullptr;
HBITMAP hbmMask = ::CreateDIBSection( hDC, &bmiMask, DIB_RGB_COLORS,
                                      reinterpret_cast< void** >( &byMask ),
                                      nullptr, 0 );
BYTE bgraMask[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
for( int i = 0; i < 16 * 16; i++ )
    for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
        byMask[ i * 4 + j ] = bgraMask[ j ];
byMask[ 0 ] = 0x00; byMask[ 1 ] = 0x00; byMask[ 2 ] = 0x00; byMask[ 3 ] = 0x00;

BITMAPINFO bmiColor = {};
bmiColor.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof( bmiColor.bmiHeader );
bmiColor.bmiHeader.biWidth = 16;
bmiColor.bmiHeader.biHeight = -16; // starts with top row
bmiColor.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmiColor.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
BYTE *byColor = nullptr;
HBITMAP hbmColor = ::CreateDIBSection( hDC, &bmiColor, DIB_RGB_COLORS,
                                       reinterpret_cast< void** >( &byColor ),
                                       nullptr, 0 );
BYTE bgraColor[] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
for( int i = 0; i < 16 * 16; i++ )
    for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
        byColor[ i * 4 + j ] = bgraColor[ j ];
byColor[ 0 ] = 0x00; byColor[ 1 ] = 0x00; byColor[ 2 ] = 0x00; byColor[ 3 ] = 0x00;

ICONINFO ii = {};
ii.fIcon = TRUE;
ii.xHotspot = ii.yHotspot = 0;
ii.hbmMask = hbmMask;
ii.hbmColor = hbmColor;
HICON hIcon = ::CreateIconIndirect( &ii );
::SendMessage( hwndDialog, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL,
               reinterpret_cast< LPARAM >( hIcon ) );
```

According to MSDN ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd183376(v=vs.85) ) each pixel's data consists of 4 bytes: blue, green, red, and an unused byte.

I made some experiments with the data by changing the values of byMask and byColor, then doing a screen shot and reading the exact RGB value in MS Paint. (Each time I placed Notepad directly behind the application's windows to have a constant background for eventual transparency / alpha channel effects.)

First I changed only the top left corner, while the rest of the data was 0x00 for the mask and 0xff for the color. The result: most of the icon was white (as expected) and the top left pixel had the following colors:

```
MR MA CR CA OR OG OB

00 00 00 ff 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 d3 e9 fe
00 00 ff 00 d3 e9 fe (a)
ff 00 00 00 d3 e9 fe
ff ff 00 00 d3 e9 fe
00 ff 00 00 d3 e9 fe
00 00 ff ff ff 00 00 (b)
ff 00 ff ff ff 00 00
ff ff ff ff ff 00 00
00 ff ff ff ff 00 00
```

After that I changed each pixel in both bitmaps to the same value. (And checked with MS Paint's fill tool that the picture has only one color.)

```
MR MA CR CA OR OG OB

00 00 00 ff 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 ff 00 ff 00 00 (c)
ff 00 00 00 00 00 00
ff ff 00 00 00 00 00
00 ff 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 ff ff ff 00 00 (d)
ff 00 ff ff ff 00 00 (d)
ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 (d)
00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 (d)
```

Abbreviations: M=mask C=Color O=Observation R=red G=green B=blue A=alpha/4.byte

I don't understand the following (letters refer to rows in the above table):

- If the 4. byte is ignored, and not an alpha channel, why is pixel (a) not ff0000 like (b)?
- If I change other pixels only, why does the first one change: (c) vs (a)?
- Why is the result of all rows marked with (d) the same, why does the mask have no effect here?

Is there a bug in my code? Am I looking at the wrong MSDN page?

Comment: If you want to use a mask bitmap then I think it has to be 1bpp. Otherwise you can use a 32bpp image bitmap with alpha channel by creating the bitmap using a `BITMAPV5HEADER` with appropriate bitfield masks (and in that case, the mask bitmap is just a dummy and isn't used).

Comment: This alpha channel thing was suspicious to me because the d3e9fe looks like some transparency was applied. Is this behavior documented somewhere? I did not find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createiconindirect and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-iconinfo

Comment: I set the biSize field to the size of the BITMAPHEADER structure, and checked it in the debugger that it is 40. is it possible that my input is taken as a BITMAPV5HEADER, which has a size of 120?

Comment: No. Versioning here is done purely based on the size you provide. If you pass a value of 40, the system will interpret the data as a `BITMAPHEADER`.

Comment: Sorry, that should read *"will interpret the data as a `BITMAPINFOHEADER`"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it. For historical reasons, there are two types of 32 bit/pixel bitmaps: those that use 3 bytes for the 3 colors, and the last one is unused (usually set to 0), and those that use the fourth byte to represent the alpha channel.

The catch is that the type is not indicated by any field but Windows takes it as an old format bitmap (without alpha) if all 4th bytes are zero, and treats it as a new format (with alpha) one if any fourth byte differs from zero. So this will result in a fully black icon:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 16 * 16; i++ )
    for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
        byColor[ i * 4 + j ] = 0x00;
```

But if I add this line to the above, the whole icon becomes transparent*:

```
byColor[ 7 * 16 + 7 + 0 ] = 0x01;
```

* Except for the pixel in row 7 column 7, which will be only 255/256 transparent.

Comment: There's really only one type of 32bpp bitmaps. The quirkiness is in the API calls you use to operate on them. Very few of the GDI calls (e.g. [`AlphaBlend`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend)) are prepared to handle alpha-transparency. Most of them will just ignore the alpha channel altogether, and some will guess, to distinguish between DIB's that do and do not have an alpha channel. [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 3: Alpha-blended images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101021-00/?p=12483) has more info on the topic.